# What's the difference between $rootScope.$new() and $rootScope.$new(true)?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Can anyone help to understand the difference between `$rootScope.$new()` and `$rootScope.$new(true)` ?
As per my understanding, they should be the same, since `$rootScope` doesn't have a parent scope.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first parameter of `$new` decides whether the new scope shall be isolated or not.

Consider the following:

```
$rootScope.data = { property: 'Value' };

var childA = $rootScope.$new();

var childB = $rootScope.$new(true);
```

`childA` will not be isolated and will have access to `data` due to prototypal inheritance.

`childB` will be isolated and will not inherit from `$rootScope` (actually it can still access `data` via the `$parent` property, but that is another issue).